# Error message when I test the connection of a database using PowerBuilder

Tags: powerbuilder

I couldn't connect to a data source using Powerbuilder. The OS is Windows 8 64; PowerBuilder 12.5;
Error message is:

> SQLSTATE=IM003
>   Specified driver could not be loaded due to system error 193: (SQL Anywhere 12, C:\Program Files\SQL Anywhere 12\Bin64\dbodbc12.dll).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PowerBuilder 12.5 is a 32bit application so you will need 32bit SQL Anywhere.

Comment: Thank you. I solved this problem by modifying the installation of the SQLAnywhere12 to add the 32 bits.